# Convert 12 hours to 24 hours from varchar column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

In my existing SQL Server database, there is a column like this:

- Column name and type: `meeting_time varchar(22)`
- Values stored: `02:30:PM`

Now I want to convert it into 24 hours format. i.e., it should convert to 14.30

When I tried this:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), meeting_time, 1) 
FROM 
    group_info 
WHERE 
    MGI_Id = 1
```

It will return the same value which stored in this column. When I tried with converting it into time or datetime, it throws exception.

Can anyone please help me!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The best solution would be to stop storing time information as varchar.

Comment: @SeanLange: Its actually for migration purpose. Existing database as like that.

Comment: Do you really have a colon after the time?

Comment: @SeanLange Yes it is!!

Comment: LOL good thing you are migrating to something more sensible. :)

Comment: Try, 
SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'Mar 22 2017 02:30PM',100)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
select convert(time, stuff(meeting_time, 6,  1, ' '))
```

Not sure if it works with all locales / languages, so you should check that first.

This assumes that your date is always in the same format, that the extra `:` is in the 6th character.

Comment: Beat me by about 15 seconds. :D